# Neo4j keeps crashing

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j is crashing on me multiple times per day.  I am running the Enterprise 2.1.2 edition on a Ubunutu 14 box with 16gb RAM and a 6-core proc.  The graph is not very large, however I am continually running out of heap space, and the database becomes unresponsive requiring a restart.  This is horrible as it is crashing the website several times per day, I am super frustrated, and not really sure what to do.

I would be happy to provide any additional info you may require to help me debug.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please share your server config `data/log/*` and `data/graph.db/messages.log`. If you use enterprise you should also be eligible for support, so perhaps raise a support ticket as well. Could you also provide more details on: your graph model, the queries you're running, the driver you use etc?